# Konva - Export to High Quality Image and crop unwanted stage area

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konva

Currently I am exporting Konva as an image using the below when user clicks a button:

```
export const Demo = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef();
  const signature = "Example text";
  const onSave = () => {
    const data = canvasRef?.current?.toDataURL({
      pixelRatio: 2
    });
  }

  return (<>
  <Stage
      ref={canvasRef}
      width={300}
      height={40}    >
      <Layer>
        <Text
          text={signature}
          verticalAlign="middle"
          fillStyle="#FF0000"
          fontSize={30}
          width={300}
          height={40}
        />
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
    <button onClick={onSave}/>
  </>)
}
```

The issue is, this will export the entire area of the Konva stage.   Is there a way to export Konva where I can get the image from a specific area of the stage - not the entire stage. For example the image should only be of my text object.

Similar to https://gist.github.com/remy/784508 ?

Comment: HTML5 does not have a 'background' color. Konva relies on HTML5 canvas to visualize its output.  To get a background color, add a Rect the same dimensions as the stage, filled with whatever color you want to replace the transparency.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat sorry i rephrased my question, I want to crop the whitespace around the Konva stage content (e.g. just download an image of the text and not any whitespace around it)

Answer (score 3):

The stage.toDataURL() method has a config object, explained here https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Stage.html#toDataURL__anchor that allow you to export a targeted rectangle from the stage.

You can use this to reduce the excess space around the area intended for the exported image.